# Function isn't executed on button press

Tags: flutter, dart

in my code I have a page with a form on it. Once the form is filled out, the user can tap a check icon in the top bar. When tapped, it's supposed to execute a function that submits the data from the form into the firestore database and return the user to the home page. However, for some reason, the function never actually gets executed.
Here's the function that's supposed to be executed:

```
  void _createRide(String origin, String destination, DateTime date,
  TimeOfDay time, int seats) async {
try {
  await _firestore.collection('rides').add({
    'origin': origin,
    'destination': destination,
    'date': date.toString().split(' ')[0],
    'time': time.format(context),
    'seats': seats,
    'driver': {
      'id': _user?.uid ?? '', // use ? and ?? operators to handle null case
      'name': _user?.displayName ??
          'Anonymous', // use ? and ?? operators to handle null case
    },
    'passengers': [],
  });
  Navigator.pop(context); // go back to home page
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
} }
```

And here's the button that's supposed to execute the function:

```
          IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.check),
        onPressed: () {
          int seats = int.parse(_seatsController.text);
          // create a new ride document using the user's input
          context.findAncestorStateOfType<_HomePageState>()?._createRide(
              _originController.text,
              _destinationController.text,
              _date!,
              _time!,
              seats); // use ? operator to handle null case
        },
```

Comment: try to debug/print `context.findAncestorStateOfType<_HomePageState>()?` can be null

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I get this when I print ```context.findAncestorStateOfType<_HomePageState>()?```: ```Closure: () => _HomePageState? from Function 'findAncestorStateOfType':.```

Comment: are you sure you are not getting error and it is not getting printed?